# How receive data from kafka from specific date

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to subscribe to topic and receive data from specific date. The method call throws exception:

> Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException: Local: Erroneous state

My code:

```cs
adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(_kafkaConfig.AsEnumerable()).Build();
var topicMetadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(_config.Topic, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var partitions = topicMetadata
    .Topics
    .First(x => x.Topic == _config.Topic)
    .Partitions;
var partitionsOffsets = partitions
    .Select(x => new TopicPartitionTimestamp(_config.Topic, x.PartitionId, new Timestamp(_config.OffsetDateUtc)));

consumer = CreateConsumer();

foreach (var p in partitions)
{
    consumer.Assign(new TopicPartition(_config.Topic, p.PartitionId));
}

var offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(partitionsOffsets, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

//await Task.Delay(1000);

foreach (var o in offsets)
{
    consumer.Seek(o);
}
```

If I add awaiting: `await Task.Delay(1000);`. Method `Seek()` doesn't throw exception. How I set offset by date, without `Task.Delay`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

next code work correct!

```cs
var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(_kafkaConfig.AsEnumerable()).Build();
var topicMetadata = adminClient.GetMetadata(_config.Topic, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var partitions = topicMetadata
    .Topics
    .First(x => x.Topic == _config.Topic)
    .Partitions;
var partitionsOffsets = partitions
    .Select(x => new TopicPartitionTimestamp(_config.Topic, x.PartitionId, new Timestamp(_config.OffsetDateUtc)));

consumer = CreateConsumer();

var offsets = consumer.OffsetsForTimes(partitionsOffsets, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

foreach (var o in offsets)
{
    consumer.Assign(o); 
}
```

Comment: Can u explain little bit more, How u  read the kafka topic based on dateTime along with some code here?  thanks in Advance